# Android Studio: Resource file does not exist in library project

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I am using Android Studio and have recently changed my build.gradle file in project A from `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` to `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` to be able to use it as library in another project say B. But now it shows resource not found error for libraries I have used in A like this.

`Error:(165, 104) error: package android.support.v7.appcompat.R does not exist`

Not just for appcompat but for few others too.

I have done "Sync project with gradle files", clean project, and few others suggested in other threads like `gradlew clean`. But still getting the same error.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [appcompat v7 package does not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24842927/appcompat-v7-package-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

Remove the prefix `android.support.v7.appcompat.`, and simply used the `R.id.<your_id>`.

This might be related to the way dependencies work in Gradle, where you no longer have to specify the full path of the R file.

Found a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24842927/appcompat-v7-package-does-not-exist).

Hope it helps..